# Using case update in cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, case

I have below 2 tables. One is dept a

```
   DEPT_NO DEPT_NAME                      DEPT_VALUE
---------- ------------------------------ ----------
        10 Chemistry                             100
        40 Physics                               600
        20 Mathematics                           200
        30 Biology                               300
        50 Cosmos                                550
```

other one is updated_dept b

```
      DEPT DEPT_NAME                      DEPT_UPDATED_VALUE
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------
        10 Chemistry                                                 
        20 Mathematics                                               
        30 Biology                                                   
        90 Astrology                                                 
        40 Numerology                                                
        50 Cosmos
```

With the help of the cursor, I want to fetch `a.dept_value` from 1st table dept a and on basis of `(a.dept_no=b.dept and a.dept_name=b.dept_name)` update column `dept_updated_value` in 2nd table updated_dept b using case.
If combination of `dept_no` and `dept_name` is not found, I want to update `dept_updated_value` to 0

I have written below code but it's not giving correct result. Please help

```
declare
    v_dept dept.dept_no%type;
    v_dept_name dept.dept_name%type;
    v_dept_value dept.dept_value%type;

    cursor c_dept_update
    is 
        select dept_no, dept_name, dept_value from dept;
begin
    open c_dept_update;

    loop
        fetch c_dept_update into v_dept,v_dept_name, v_dept_value;
        exit when c_dept_update%notfound;

        update dept_updated
        set    dept_updated_value=
               case 
                   when dept=v_dept and dept_name=v_dept_name
                       then v_dept_value
                   else 0
               end;

        commit;
    end loop;

    close c1;
end;
```

result is like this

```
DEPT DEPT_NAME                                DEPT_UPDATED_VALUE
---------- ---------------------------------- ------------------
        10 Chemistry                                           0
        20 Mathematics                                         0
        30 Biology                                             0
        90 Astrology                                           0
        40 Numerology                                          0
        50 Cosmos                                            550
```

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase Steven Feuerstein, don't do in a loop what you can do in SQL. So I'd join the tables in an updatable inline view. I haven't tested this so it may need tweaking:

```
UPDATE ( SELECT b.dept, b.dept_name, b.dept_updated_value, a.dept AS dept2
           FROM updated_dept b
           LEFT JOIN dept a ON a.dept = b.dept AND a.dept_name = b.dept_name )
   SET dept_updated_value = NVL( dept2, 0 )
```